# RStudio blogdown generates error after using new_site()

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

After successfully loading blogdown and installing Hugo, I have trouble creating a new site with new_site(dir = 'test') in an empty 'test' folder. First, I get the following positive message:

Congratulations! Your new Hugo site is created in C:....\Dropbox\test.

Just a few more steps and you're ready to go:

1. Download a theme into the same-named folder.
   or create your own with the "hugo new theme " command.
2. Perhaps you want to add some content. You can add single files
   with "hugo new \.".
3. Start the built-in live server via "hugo server".

trying URL 'https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium-theme/archive/master.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 119666 bytes (116 KB)
downloaded 116 KB

**Now comes the error msg.**

> Error in list.files(dir) : invalid 'path' argument

The current R session info gives this:

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] blogdown_0.0.35

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bookdown_0.3.19 tools_3.3.2     rstudioapi_0.6  knitr_1.15.20

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a [temporary bug](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/aa70a965703c4c0b1f84a4bb2a5176e3adf7885f) that existed for a couple of hours. Please reinstall **blogdown** from Github:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```